# ADF needs access to blob storage that is a part of virtual network

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account, azure-private-link, linked-service

I have create one azure data factory that needs access to blob storage which is a part of virtual network.

While creating the linked service in ADF, it fails and cannot connect to blob storage since the access to the blob storage is allowed using 'Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses' option.

How can I configure the Azure blob settings or is there a way to give ADF access to blob storage following the best practices and providing a secured connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to your **storage account >> Networking >> Resource Instances** and add the resource type and Instance name  to allow access to specific resource instances.

[image]

**NOTE:** Make sure the instance belongs to the same tenant as your Storage account and have roles assigned to perform operations on blobs.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-azure-resource-instances).
2. [Azure built-in roles for blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs)